# Crash - CL_magma - Couldn't load the default shader

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I use Here sdk for mapping, and the app crashes, and in the logs I see "CL_magma - Couldn't load the default shader. It happens in Xcode simulators and real iOS devices.

I tried searching to see if anyone had the same problem but couldn't find anything for iOS.

Perhaps someone has encountered similar crashes, please help.